# How do I turn off these vertical lines in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

How do I turn off these vertical lines in PyCharm?  I have looked all over the place in the editor and can't find out how.  Also have tried to google but I don't know what they are called.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General`
2. `Code Folding --> Show code folding outline`

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it.